# How to Omit Text qualifier in json/csv extracter, while inserting rows in ADLA?

Tags: json, csv, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I've have a file of csv/json type and trying to insert into a table in ADLA.
But my data column looks like "Nike", which should be like Nike(Without quotes).

I've tried using "**quoting:true**" but this so far doesn't allow skiping textqualifier , like to do doing import into sql server database.

[Source File](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtFu80OEpmZKgRb9uq1fX9R0rQeP)

**Sample Code**

```
DECLARE @in  string = "/Samples/Data/UsqlTwo.csv";
DECLARE @out string = "/output/trckouttwo.csv";

 @CustData =
     EXTRACT CustomerUniqueID   int             ,
     CusLocationID              int             ,
     [PIM]                      int             ,
     AgeGender                  string          ,
     Mood                       string          ,
     StartDate                  DateTime        ,
     ImagePath                  string          ,
     EndDate                    DateTime        ,
     OutletName                 string          ,
     OutletStreet               string          ,
     OutletCity                 string          ,
     OutletState                string          ,
     OutletAreaCode             string          ,
     OutletCountry              string          ,
     Outletlandmark             string          ,
     OutletWeather              string          ,
     BrandName                  string          ,
     BrandStreet                string          ,
     BrandCity                  string          ,
     BrandState                 string          ,
     BrandAreaCode              string          ,
     BrandCountry               string          ,
     Brandlandmark              string          ,
     CamLocName                 string          ,
     CamAddress                 string          ,
     CamZone                    string          ,
     CamContactName             string          ,
     CamEmailID                 string          ,
     CamPhone                   string          ,
     CamNotloc                  string          ,
     CamNotZon                  string          ,
     CamNotContctName           string          ,
     CamNotPhone                string          ,
     CamNotEmailID              string          ,
     CamSMSNot                  string

     FROM @in
//     USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);
USING Extractors.Csv(quoting:true);


@Branddetail= SELECT DISTINCT BrandName        

     FROM @CustData;



     INSERT INTO CLSTrackOMeter.dbo.Brand
(BrandId ,Name ,AddressId ,SuperAdminDetails )

SELECT 3 AS BrandId, BrandName,3 AS AddressId,"Admin" AS SuperAdminDetails FROM @Branddetail;
```

**Result in table**
[image]

**Expected result should be there without quotes**

Answer (score 1):

I think you have output your file without specifying `quoting : false` in the outputter.  The default value for this is `true` as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt492750.aspx#quoting), so quotes will appear for strings unless you explicitly ask for them not to.

As far as quotes appearing in the table, I cannot reproduce your issue.  `quoting : true` works perfectly well and will remove quotes from files.  If you then output that file (which I think you have done, not insert it into a table as per your script), simply specify `quoting:false` will remove the quotes from the output file, like this:

```
...
OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```